# Should I add modernizr.js and normalize.css to a Zurb Foundation 6 project?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm a newbie in this subject, but my question is: should I or do I need to add modernizr.js and normalize.css to a Zurb Foundation 6 project?

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/3160-foundations-dependency-on-modernizr

Answer (score 2):

You need not include normalize.css or other normalization stylesheet.  Foundation 6 depends on [normalize-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-scss) and the generated [`foundation.css`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/v6.3.0/dist/css/foundation.css) includes it.  Once you link it on your HTML page, it will be "normalized".

If you need [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/), you can include it in your project, for example by its [modernizr NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr).  It is not integrated in Foundation 6 any more.  You can link [`modernizr.js`](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js) from your HTML page in addition to [`foundation.js`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/v6.3.0/dist/js/foundation.js).